# LINQ: Drill down to value in query results

Tags: linq, entity-framework-4, .net-4.5

I am using LINQ for the first time and have the following query:

```
var query = from c in context.Call
            join d in context.CallData on c.CallID = d.CallID
            where c.CallID == 123
            select new {
               c.CallID,
               c.CallResult,
               d.FieldID,
               d.FieldValue
            };
```

This returns data similar to the following

```
c.CallID    c.CallResult   d.FieldID    d.FieldValue
  123         Sale           345          John
  123         Sale           346          Doe
  123         Sale           347          888-222-3333
```

How can drill down to the row containing d.FieldID = 346 to get the value of d.FieldValue (346 being the LastName field)?  I would like to use this value as the new value of a local variable:

```
// I know this doesn't work, just showing what I would like to accomplish
string LastName = query.Select(a => a.FieldID = 346).FieldValue;
```

Conversely, how can I change the value of c.CallResult once I have these results?  Since it is a join, can I simply change one row of data or do I have to do a separate query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first question you can move on from your `query` variable:

```
var fieldValue = query.Where(x => x.FieldID == 346).Single().FieldValue;
```

As for your second question: you must apply a change to the original entity object:

```
var call = context.Find(123);
// or context.Calls.Single(c => c.CallId == 123) if this is not DbContext.
call.CallResult = newValue;
context.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean:

```
string LastName = query
                 .Where(a => a.FieldID = 346)
                 .Select(a => a.FieldValue)
                 .FirstOrDefault();
```